# How to transfer multiple files using go

Tags: file, go, transfer

I am trying to write a program in go which has two parts. One part is the client who tries to upload multiple pictures to the other part the server.

The server side should do the following:

1. Get the number of files which will be send
2. Loop for every file
3. Get filename
4. Get the file and save it
5. Go to 3

So far the server side is doing the following:

```
func getFileFromClient(connection net.Conn) {
    var numberOfPics int
    var err error
    var receivedBytes int64
    var fileName string
    r := bufio.NewReader(connection)
    strNumberOfPics, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Read: %s\n", strNumberOfPics)
    strNumberOfPics = strings.Trim(strNumberOfPics, "\n")
    numberOfPics, err = strconv.Atoi(strNumberOfPics)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error Atoi: %s\n", err)
        panic("Atoi")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Receiving %d pics:\n", numberOfPics)
    for i := 0; i < numberOfPics; i++ {
        // Getting the file name:
        fileName, err = r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error receiving: %s\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Filename: %s\n", fileName)
        fileName = strings.Trim(fileName, "\n")
        f, err := os.Create(fileName)
        defer f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error creating file")
        }
        receivedBytes, err = io.Copy(f, connection)
        if err != nil {
            panic("Transmission error")
        }

        fmt.Printf("Transmission finished. Received: %d \n", receivedBytes)
    }
}
```

io.Copy is working for just one file and nothing additional (because it does not empty the queue I think). I do not want to reconnect every time for every file if I do not have too. But I am not sure what I actually can do about that.

Has anyone any suggestions of an existing package or method which could help? Or  example code? Or am I just plain wrong and it is a bad idea to even try this with go?

I think it might be enough if the server is able to flush the connection buffer after every read so no additional info is read and/or copied.

Really looking forward for help, thanks in advance

EDIT: Updated Code still not working. I think it might be the bufio.reader

```
func getFileFromClient(connection net.Conn) {
    var numberOfPics int
    var err error
    var receivedBytes int64
    var fileName string
    r := bufio.NewReader(connection)
    strNumberOfPics, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    strNumberOfPics = strings.Trim(strNumberOfPics, "\n")
    numberOfPics, err = strconv.Atoi(strNumberOfPics)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error Atoi: %s\n", err)
        panic("Atoi")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Receiving %d pics:\n", numberOfPics)
    for i := 0; i < numberOfPics; i++ {
        // Getting the file name:
        fileName, err = r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error receiving: %s\n", err)
        }
        fileName = strings.Trim(fileName, "\n")
        fmt.Printf("Filename: %s\n", fileName)
        f, err := os.Create(fileName)
        defer f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error creating file")
        }
        // Get the file size
        strFileSize, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Read size error %s\n", err)
            panic("Read size")
        }
        strFileSize = strings.Trim(strFileSize, "\n")
        fileSize, err := strconv.Atoi(strFileSize)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error size Atoi: %s\n", err)
            panic("size Atoi")
        }
        fmt.Printf("Size of pic: %d\n", fileSize)

        receivedBytes, err = io.CopyN(f, connection, int64(fileSize))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Transmission error: %s\n", err)
            panic("Transmission error")
        }
        fmt.Printf("Transmission finished. Received: %d \n", receivedBytes)
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: I did not get this solution to work. I am pretty sure it is because  I used bufio. I did however get it to work by transmitting a single zip file with io.copy. Another solution which worked was to transmit a zip file by using http. If you are stuck trying something similar and need help feel free to send me a message. Thanks to all of you for your help

Comment: Why not use an existing protocol to transfer the images? You have no way of delimiting the image data, you just copy away until the client closes the connection.

Comment: When you say existing you mean protocols like ftp? The idea of the project is to have multiple clients who upload pictures to a webserver, the webserver then arranges these pictures in proper directories and a webpage should then display all of them under a specific url. I do not want these clients to have actual access to the server. They should just be able to use the client program and it uploads them automatically. Thanks for the fast answer btw!

Comment: If you send images serially, you also need to send the size of each one before, so you know how many bytes to read. `io.Copy` will read until EOF, so you should use `io.CopyN` instead.

Comment: Why ftp? HTTP is well understood and would allow to transfer all files in one go.

Comment: io.CopyN sounds like the perfect solutions. Could have found that myself I guess ... Will try it and if it works and you submit your solution I will mark it. Thanks guys

Comment: If you are running this on a webserver, then you already have a perfectly good wire protocol, with minimal overhead -- HTTP. Just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your implementation so far, the thing you're missing is that [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) reads from source until it finds an EOF, so it will read all the remaining images in one go.

Also, the client **must send, for each image, its size in bytes** (you could do that after sending the name).
In the server, just read the size and then use [`io.CopyN()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyN) to read that exact number of bytes.

**EDIT**: as a matter of fact, you could also do things like you were doing and send images in parallel instead of serially, that would mean you open a new connection for each file transfer and then read all of the file withouth needing to send the amount of images or their size.

In case you want an alternative, a good option would be using good 'ol HTTP and multipart requests. There's the built-in module [mime/multipart](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) that allows you to do file transfers over HTTP. Of course, that would mean you'd have to rewrite your program.

Comment: @Wirsiing: just note that this framing protocol that you've come up with has no response from the server, so the client has no way to confirm that all the files actually arrived in full.

Comment: @JimB True, everything would have to be implemented from scratch in this case. Of course, HTTP would save all these headaches but, if nothing else, you have full control of how the data is sent, the overhead and you could optimize transfers differently...

Comment: It is still only working for the first file though. Is copyN actually setting my read pointer  ?

Comment: @Wirsiing it sets the read pointer correctly, you can check it from this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i5lBIlVYki), are you sure you are sending the correct size and not skipping anything?

Comment: I saw the playground but I do not think it is working in my case might because I use the bufio reader. The first transmission is working like a charm but for the second I only get gibberish for the filename and the size after that. I updated my OP with the new code. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to zip all the images you want to transfer and then send them as a single multipart POST request. In that way you have a standard way of knowing all your Acceptance criteria.

You can easily zip multiple files using `https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/`

Comment: This is so simple and so good. But I will just use io.Copy with a single zip archive which is the easiest solution